# RabbitMQ: Publishing message when consumer is down and later consumer can't consume message without named queue

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

I have a producer and a consumer. **Multiple instances** of the consumer are running. When producer publishes a message, my intention is to consume the message by all the instances. So, I am using the direct exchange. Producer publishes a message to the direct exchange with a topic. Consumers are listening to that topic with the exclusive queue. This process is working fine when the consumer is up and producer publishes a message. But when consumers are down and producer publishes a message, consumers are not consuming this message when up.

I googled about the issue. A suggestion was to use named queue. But if I use named queue, messages will be consumed following the round-robin algorithm. That does not meet my expectation to consume the same message by all the consumers.

Is there any other solution?

Appreciated your help.

Comment: Hi, I need more details to help you: Your requirement is to have all consumers consume all the messages, right? In this case, why do they have to consume all the messages, provided that they are the same instance of a consumer? The question is: what is your use case?

Comment: Niloy - do you understand what a fanout exchange is? That is probably what you want.

Comment: @cdelmas, I have two application. Let's say appA, appB. I do some caching in appB. But in appA there are some operation which may change some data which is cached in appB. So, this is done through RabbitMQ instead of REST API. Now, I have multiple instance of appB. So, I want that all the instances cache to be updated. In that case, when appA publishes any messages to the MQ, all the instances of appB must consume the message to update their caches. 

This is my story. Let me know if you need further information.

Comment: @LukeBakken, Yes, I understand fanout exchange is. Please check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53863678/rabbitmq-publishing-message-when-consumer-is-down-and-later-consumer-cant-cons?noredirect=1#comment94583390_53865142

Comment: I don't think you do, because my understanding of your description is that you should use a fanout exchange. If you want the same message to be sent to multiple consumers, you use a fanout exchange and each consumer declares its own (possibly exclusive) queue that is bound to that exchange. The best path forward at this point would be to share an example of _what you have tried_ (in code form) and explain how that is not meeting your goals.

Comment: @LukeBakken Let's say I am using fanout exchange with the exclusive queue. What will happen if the consumers are down and publisher publish a message in the MQ? When the consumers are up, will they consume the message? In my system, the consumer is not consuming the message. I am asking for a solution or hint to solve this particular situation.

Comment: @NiloyDatta I agree with LukeBakken and that's what i explained you in my answer. If u use named queues with fanout exchange you are good. Bind a queue named "to_app_A" and connect consumer appA, bind another queue "to_app_B" and connect consumer B, bind those queues to a fanout exchange, and you're done. Also, in your use case you can't use exclusive queues since the purpose of this is to delete the queue when the consumer disconnects. https://www.rabbitmq.com/queues.html

Comment: @Artandor My consumers are the instance of the same application. How is it possible to use named queue here?

Comment: "Let's say I am using fanout exchange with the exclusive queue. What will happen if the consumers are down and publisher publish a message in the MQ? When the consumers are up, will they consume the message?" - No, they won't. You would have to use durable, named queues to catch messages in this case. Since they are bound to a fanout exchange, they will get all messages published to the exchange. Naming these queues is up to you.

Comment: @LukeBakken Thanks for your suggestions and valuable time.

Comment: @NiloyDatta I don't understand why you think it is an issue that they are instances of the same application. I did read your update and i think you should just give it a try. I'll make you a schema to make it clear to you, because I feel like we struggle to understand each other.

Comment: Here is a schema : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-7gL6EhJsquThAIENX6ubARLM7wxGOXr/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @Artandor Please check the thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15101640/when-to-use-direct-exchange-over-fanout-exchange

My problem is not related to exchange type in any way. I just want to ensure that, when consumer is down and producer publish a message, will consumer consume the message later? Please keep in mind that, I am not using NAMED QUEUE.

Comment: The type of exchange you use doesn't matter at all here. If you don't have named queue, you have no queue your consumer can reconnect to after crashing. If you use exclusive queues it's even worse, because exclusive means that when consumer disconnect, the queue is deleted. If you ARE NOT USING NAMED QUEUE then you misunderstood how rabbitmq works, and since you are not likely to change it i can't help you. Note that I had a similar use case and what i describe you here works. Also, using a direct exchange to publish the same content to all your queues / consumers is a waste of time.

Answer (score 0):

There are two solutions to your issue.

Using named queue is one of them.
Set your exchange in fanout mode and subscribe your named queues to it. Doing so, when a publisher send a message in your exchange, it will be dispatched to all the queues listening.

You can then have one or more consumer for each queue (allowing you to scale). You'll have to define a named queue / consumer. When one consumer disconnect, his queue still receive messages and when he comes back he can consume them.

You should be able to do what you want that way.

The other way is more for your personnal knowledge since you said you want to use RabbitMQ. But in that particular case you could use Kafkha, your consummer could then, after reconnection, resume at the message index he was when he disconnected.

Please update me if it doesn't work :)

Comment: Kafka option is discarded as my problem is specific to RabbitMQ. If I use named queue and multiple consumer listen to that queue, will not the messages be distributed following the round-robin algorithm as I mentioned in my question? @Artandor

Comment: If a consumer listen to that queue he will be able to consume messages in round robin, indeed. But every queues will be a destination for a specific consumer. 
For example, i have two consumers. They are bound on a fanout exchange, therefore every message i push to this exchange is dispatched to both of them.
Consumer one is connected on queue (example) named "to_consumer_one". If he disconnects, he will just have to reconnect to "to_consumer_one" to retrieve his messages.
If you connect two consumers to this queue messages will be distributed in round robin, but this is scalability ?